# Is there a way to compose "select" and "update" api functions for a model in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api

The title might be a bit misleading, but what I want to do is to interact with a model in many different ways. The api call is sent in from the frontend and Laravel is just a backend

So for example,

I might need to do this:

Select model with criteria A and update using function X 
Select model with criteria A and update using function Y 
Select model with criteria B and update using function X 
Select model with criteria B and update using function Y.

As you can see, I have two criteria for selecting, and two ways I might want to update the models I have selected. However this gives me 4 different routes / controllers.

I understand that there are many ways to do it, but what is the best way in api design?

For now I have two ways:

1. Select in 1 api call and update in a second call (but requires 2 calls)
2. Pass in a pre-defined string to the api to define which select function to use  (reasonable solution?)

Comment: I think the design pattern is beyond `laravel` scope. Maybe you want to read something about `GraphQL` which might be more flexible

Answer (score 0):

One way I would handle this is with a service file and a controller

So you have 1 route and 1 controller and 1 function in that controller.

your functions (function X), (function Y), (get criteria A) and (get criteria b) would be static functions in a service file.

Your controller would then do checks to see which functions to call in your service and pass back the correct data to the controller, these checks would be based on your passed data to the controller.

for example..

```
public function MyControllerFunction(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if ($request['updateFunctionY']) {
              MyService::updateFunctionY($request['value1'],$request['value2']);
            }
            if ($request['updateFunctionX']) {
              MyService::updateFunctionX($request['value1'],$request['value2']);
            }
            if ($request['criteria A']) {
              return MyService::getCriteriaA();
            }
            if ($request['criteria B']) {
                  return MyService::getCriteriaB();
            }
            return Respond::Bad('something went wrong');
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return Respond::InternalServerError('An Error Occured', $th);
        }
    }
```

Not sure if this is a get route, post route ext.. ?
Also not sure if criteria A and criteria B are different models/tables or different conditions on the same model/table?

This is just a vague example but use of services really help, these functions can be used again elsewhere in a controller, to help reduce code and maintain consistency